# After install, mySQL doesn' start (windows10, source install)

Tags: mysql

I'm installing Apache server, php, and MySQL on Windows10. 
First two was successful but MySQL has a problem.

I installed MySQL into `C:\mysql-5.7.10-winx64`, and changed `my.ini` like this

```
basedir = C:/mysql-5.7.10-winx64
datadir = C:/mysql-5.7.10-winx64/data
port = 3306
```

I succeeded install but if I try to start, it shows like below

```
C:\Windows\system32>net start mysql
The MySQL service is starting.
The MySQL service could not be started.
The service did not report an error.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

However, if I check Computer `Management>Event Viewer>Custom Views>Summary` page events, it tells me "failed to set datadir to `C:\mysql-5.7.10-winx64\data\`"

[image: Error Event Description]

If I make data folder manually, error message changed to

> Can't open the `mysql.plugin` table

Please run `mysql_upgrade` to create it.." and some files are created in data folder

[image]

I tried to upgrade by typing `mysql_upgrade` but it failed.

> mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) while connecting to the MySQL server. Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try running the Command Prompt as Administrator and then execute the `net start mysql` command.

Comment: @SarathChandra sure, you can see that in my text. Command Prompt was opened as Administrator mode

Comment: This is not a software development related question. You are more likely to get an adequate answer on superuser or dba forums.

Answer (score 22):

Clear the "data" directory, then run command `mysqld  --initialize`, and the command `net start mysql`, bingo!

Comment: Thanks for answer though I had tough time to find that root password for mysql server initialized this way was in a temp file under data directory.

Answer (score 12):

1.For the error,

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) while connecting to the MySQL server. Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
```

I ran the cmd as administrator and then go to \Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\, and run

```
mysqld install
```

2.For the error,

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>net start mysql
The MySQL service is starting.
The MySQL service could not be started.
The service did not report an error.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

Try

```
mysqld --initialize
```

and then

```
net start mysql
```

Thanks to [Athan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43882384/2360723)'s answer. Those combination worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same problem and I wasted hours solving the issue, but in the end this worked.

1. Go to you `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7` and copy the `my.ini` file from there.
2. Go to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7` and **paste** it there.
3. Open `cmd` and run `net start mysql`

It would work like a charm.

**Explanation:**

`MySQL` couldn't  find `my.ini`, therefore tried to create data in `Program Files...` where it had no rights to do so, therefore it says access denied every time you run it.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is old but I was running into the same problem you were seeing. I thought I'd share this answer for anyone looking. I created the `data` directory as you did initially and tried to start the service and got "Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table `mysql.user` doesn't exist." I then deleted the contents of the `data` directory and instead initialized the `data` directory by running the following command from the `bin` folder.

```
mysqld --initialize [with random root password]

mysqld --initialize-insecure [without random root password]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, after checked this document: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html

I just clear `data` directory and add the --console option to initialize:

```bsh
bin\mysqld --defaults-file=C:\my.ini
   --initialize --console
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

For your error, main cause is in your **my.ini** setting.
Since you are installing MySQL on Windows, you should define path like:

```
basedir = C:\\mysql-5.7.10-winx64
datadir = C:\\mysql-5.7.10-winx64\\data
```

These slashes must be doubled.

Then start your MySQL service again. I guess this time would work.

And here is [official document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html) from MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Server can either be run as a Program or as a Service. You cannot run both. You should stop 'mysqld' Server Program before starting 'mysqld' Server as Service.

The 'mysqld' Server Program can be stopped either by typing 
'`CTRL + c`' or by issuing 
'`mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`' command and issue the password when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

You need download from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ previous GA versions, and after that copy directory "data" to your new mysql or outher directory what you write in configfile my.ini in directory mysql-"version" .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This saved my life,
Just turn off the windows firewall and  Give he port number correctly as 3306 as default, then restart MYSQL server . After that turn on the windows defender firewall
Just work it fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my solution is not added yet,

I've installed mysql80 , edited my.ini in windows notepad and got the same error like topic author "... NET HELPMSG 3534." when I start mysql service,

and my issue was in extra bytes added by notepad at the begining (EB BB BF) on my.ini, when I edited (added the same changes) my.ini in other editor everything worked fine.

[image]